# JavaFX SceneBuilder not working and as well as GUI is rendered very bad after installing VGA

Tags: javafx-8, scenebuilder

I have install `Jdk-8 (build 1.8.0-ea-b117)` as well as `SceneBuilder 2.0`.

My hardware configuration is:

Processor: **Intel(R)Atom(TM) CPU D2550 @ 1.86GHz 1.86GHz**
Installed memory(RAM): **2.00 GB**
System Type: **32-bit Operating System**

Before installing `VGA SceneBuilder` was working fine. As well as GUI is coming as expected

Screen shot is below

[image]

After installation of VGA on my PC whole scenebuilder GUI got deteriorated and its not working at all even many controls are not visible on scene builder.

Screen shot of scene builder is below:

[image]

What is the cause of this problem?

Comment: What does it mean to install a "VGA"?

Comment: Hi Alksandr I had install VGA drivers on my Machine after installing windows. I had specified the system parameters. I had also create an issue or jira you can check it https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-35153. This is bug of JavaFX  itself. If scenebuilder itself is not running in my system how any JavaFx application will run. So i had got the simple solution as a workaround  java -Dprism.order=sw ... which initiates Software rendering on launching JavaFx application

Comment: Please let us know what GPU you have,  what drivers and what what version.

Comment: Also, did you change the DPI in windows?

Comment: No aleksandr i havn't change the DPI. I had some information i got using java -Dprism.verbose=true.

Comment: No aleksandr i havn't change the DPI. I had some information i got using java -Dprism.verbose=true.   Prism pipeline init order: d3d sw 
Using platform text rasterizer
Using native-based Pisces rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives

Comment: Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Loading D3D native library ...
succeeded.
D3DPipelineManager: Created D3D9 device
Direct3D initialization succeeded
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Maximum supported texture size: 4096

Comment: OS Information:
Windows 7 build 7600
D3D Driver Information:
Intel(R) Graphics Media Accelerator 3600 Series
\\.\DISPLAY1
Driver igdumd32.dll, version 8.14.8.1083
Pixel Shader version 3.0
Device : ven_8086, dev_0BE2, subsys_7C451019
Max Multisamples supported: 0
 vsync: true vpipe: true
Else about GPU i had currently no information what GPU i am using. I will try to find GPU information and let you know

Comment: Instead of putting so much information in comments, you should edit the question. Hopefully Oracle will issue a prompt fix.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Aleksandr. I also think same. JavaFx has lots of problems regarding rendering of images. I had also posted a question long time ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921415/latency-in-web-cam-preview-using-opencv-javacv-with-javafx which is also seems like problem in JavaFX not in Javacv(Opencv)

Comment: Now due to problems currently i am facing regarding performance,memory leakage, I am quitting JavaFX and coding in swing. No options left

Comment: b117 is a bit outdated now. Try downloading the latest build. Java 8 is supposed to be released in 3 months. Looks like JavaFX 8 may not be ready by then?

Comment: I am agree with you Aleksandr. I will use the b121 release and let you know it solve my problem or not.